# Hiding rows in Excel based on date

Tags: excel, hide, rows

I need to automatically hide rows in excel that have a past date in column `H3:H3000`.

The code below doesn't do anything when I input it:

```
Sub HideRowsDate()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("H3:A350")
If cell.Value <= Now Then
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the **A** in H3:A350 a type or is it in your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

> For Each cell In Range("H3:**A**350")

I'll assume a typo in the above and use Range("H3:**H**350").

I strongly suspect your dates are not dates at all but text that looks like a date. Text that looks like a date will (by default in the *General* number format) be left aligned; real dates will be right aligned in a cell. Try the following modification to see if it accomplishes what you are looking for.

```
Sub HideRowsDate()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("H3:H350")
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
            If DateValue(Format(cell.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy;@")) <= Now Then
                'cell = cell.Value
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This converts text that looks like a date to an actual date so that it can be compared to *Now*. Dates that are actually dates will also be processed correctly. This duality comes from the *<date format>;<text format>* in the Format function's *format mask*. It ignores blank cells, narrative text (e.g. text that does *not* look like a date) and numbers that cannot be construed as dates.

The next logical step here would be to use the converted cell value to put an actual date into the cell. Uncomment the `cell = cell.Value` line to achieve that.